# How to make font icon?

Tags: fonts, icons

A question that "How to make font icon" like fontawasome , material icon etc , how to make it own font family?

is there any tool like photoshop or an illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a font using Fontforge software. you can have it [here](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) . draw the icons and encode in a font using the Fontforge software